# Strange behaviour of PHP DateTime Class

Tags: php, datetime, php-5.3, intervals, datediff

I'm trying to get the time difference in milliseconds.

```
$_SESSION['startTime'] = time();
$to_time = time();

//I call the code from here after a delay, say 4 seconds

$from_time = $_SESSION['startTime'];
$d1 = new DateTime($from_time);
$d2 = new DateTime($to_time);


print_r( $d1->diff($d2));
```

I print the result after 4 seconds and the result is somewhat like this:

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 4 //---- Problem, this value should be +
    [m] => 0 //                                   |
    [d] => 0 //                                   |
    [h] => 0 //                                   |       
    [i] => 0 //                                   |
    [s] => 0 //<-here-----------------------------+
    [invert] => 1
    [days] => 1461
)
```

[s] should have been 4. why the 4 is in the year section?
What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE - Solved**

```
$to_time = (microtime(true));
$from_time = ( $_SESSION['startTime']);
$diff = $to_time - $from_time;
print $diff;
```

Prints

```
3.xxxxxx
```

Comment: If you already have 2 unix timestamps, why not just subtract them directly?  Also, if you're looking for ms precision, you need microtime().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must specify the formatting. You're sending in a unix timestamp into DateTime, therefor:

```
$d1 = new DateTime($from_time);
$d2 = new DateTime($to_time);
```

Becomes

```
$d1 = new DateTime('@'.$from_time);
$d2 = new DateTime('@'.$to_time);
```

The @ symbol tells DateTime that I'm using a Unix Timestamp.

Comment: Never heard of that syntax. it gives a fatal error as well. which version of PHP you have? I have 5.3.8

Comment: OK, @Corbin 's answer actually solved my problem.
Well, I was using microtime(true) and stored in session variable. combining the value from the session variable with '@' sign produced the error.

Comment: Corbins code works, yes, but it's a lot easier to use diff if you need measurements other than seconds.

Also, there's a small flaw. You set both $to_time and $from_time to the time the first part was called, as the second time() is called before the delay.

Comment: "The @ symbol tells DateTime that I'm using a Unix Timestamp." Does it? I don't see that in the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php). Isn't it just causing php to cast the integer timestamp to a string?

Comment: [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php)
Half way down the page in example 2 it shows that a string like '@2034056043' will be parsed as a UNIX Timestamp, and the $to_time variable holds one of those timestamps.

Comment: So it does. I wonder why it's not explicitly mentioned in the docs?

Comment: It's a formatting thing- The DateTime constructor can handle a lot of different formats, which is all explained somewhere else in the docs. A bit like what they do with the print family.. Linking everything to printf for formatting instructions.

Answer (score 0):

The [constructor for DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) accepts a string as a parameter not a timestamp, which is why you are seeing the "strange behaviour".

You need to expressly set the timestamp after insantiating a DateTime object:-

```
$from_time = $_SESSION['startTime'];
$d1 = new DateTime();
$d1->setTimestamp($from_time);
```